# Redirect Code in httpd.ini or html

Tags: html

I'm on a windows server. I'm trying to create an html file (must be named 'notfound.html') that will allow me to have a customized 404 page for my two domains.  My hosting company said I could use HTTPD.INI to redirect browsers to the correct page.  I have no knowledge of httpd.ini.  Can someone help?

Simple put: It would involve two domains (as example) mydomain.com and myotherdomain.com.

I need to redirect visitors to a customized 404 page for both domains. mydomain.com is the primary domain.  myotherdomain.com is a subdomain under the root directory where mydomain.com resides.

Can this be done with httpd.ini?  If so how?? I hope to redirect visitors who have mistyped a webpage to a customized 404 page per domain. I know I will need to have seperate 'notfound.html' files in their respective directories.  I don't have a clue how to do this with httpd.ini.

Any suggestions? THANKS !!!!  Slim

Answer (score 0):

You could just place this row at the end of the httpd file:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /notfound.html
```

Edit: Im on mobile so I can't do any research. And you only said that you are on a windows server, not if you use IIS, Apache or any other server software. My answer only applies if you are using apache.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Helicon ISAPI_Rewrite configuration file
# Version 3.1.0.69

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCompatibility2 On
RepeatLimit 32
RewriteBase

#  Block external access to the httpd.ini and httpd.parse.errors files
RewriteRule ^/httpd(?:\.ini|\.parse\.errors).*$ / [NC,F,O]
#  Block external access to the Helper ISAPI Extension
RewriteRule ^.*\.isrwhlp$ / [NC,F,O]

RewriteRule ^/(?!(?:manager|assets)/)(.*)\.html(?:\?(.*))?$ /index.php?q=$1?2&$2: [NC,L,U]
```

Answer (score 0):

The above code works for IIS 6. May have to modify the last line at the

```
/index.php?
```

If you are using IIS Manager, cPanel or Plesk you can create these without adding the file manually through the GUI.